# Need help to figure out HD paths , append byte and the network params for these coins:

Tags: hd-wallets

I am making an HD wallet on Android. I plan to support all major tokens/coins out there. I have setup the base of HD wallets and am getting pub/priv xpub/xpriv keys at HD path.

Imagine a function like:

```
/*
     * M/44'/0'/0'/0/0 : BITCOIN  MAIN NET
     *
     * Any address has:
     * m: private key
     * M: public key
     * 44' : BIP44 (read : https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki)
     * 0' : coin bitcoin
     * 0' : account
     * 0 : External address (1 is for Internal or return address)
     * 0 : node end
     *
     * 0th Node of 1st external address of  1st account of bitcoin
     * */
    public List<ChildNumber> getBitcoinPath() {
        List<ChildNumber> childNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ChildNumber child44Hardened = new ChildNumber(44, true);
        ChildNumber child0Hardened = new ChildNumber(0,true);
        ChildNumber child1Hardened = new ChildNumber(1,true);
        ChildNumber child0 = ChildNumber.ZERO;

        childNumbers.add(child44Hardened);
        if(Environment.DEBUG) {
            childNumbers.add(child1Hardened);//testnet
        }
        else {
            childNumbers.add(child0Hardened); //mainnet
        }
        childNumbers.add(child0Hardened);
        childNumbers.add(child0);
        childNumbers.add(child0);
        return childNumbers;
    }
```

So for **Bitcoin** Path is :

> M/44'/0'/0'/0/0

Similarly Bitcoin **test** net 3:

> M/44'/1'/0'/0/0

For **Ethereum** though there are many 'official path' but i am going with most used:

> m/44'/60'/0'/0

I need help with the following:

1) the HD paths for list of these coins:

Litecoin
Dash
Bitcoin Gold
DigiByte
DogeCoin

2) The magicbyte/appendbyte for these coins.
Append byte is used to derive address from pubkey. Example bitcoin is 0x00

3) Network params for these coins. (i could probably pull this off from their source code, but if someone have them handy please do share)

In return for your help i will compile a medium post with all of this data for the future developers. Any help would be really great.

Comment: here is list for registered coin types for BIP-0044, https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md

Comment: i can help with Bitcoin Gold magicbyte/appendbytes: pub = 0x26;priv = 0x80; and HD Keys {'prv':0x0488ade4, 'pub':0x0488b21e}

Comment: i think priv key byte is same for all btc forks